# Poisson distribution probability question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The typos on a page in magazine has a Poisson distribution. The probabilty of a page having typo(s) is 0.2.

What is the probabilty that there are exactly 3 typos on a page?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to calculate the parameter of the Poisson distribution. Call the Poisson random variable X.

We have

$$ 0.8 = P(X = 0) = e^{-\lambda},$$

using the definition of the Poisson distribution.

Hence $ \lambda = -\log(0.8) = \log(5/4)$.

So $ \ \ \ P(X=3) = \dfrac{(\log(5/4))^3 e^{-\log((5/4))}}{3!} =\dfrac{2(\log(5/4))^3 }{15}. $

Comment: Thanks! Why 0.2 equals $P(x=0)$?

Comment: I'm sorry, it should $= 0.8$. I made a little mistake. I will edit now.

Comment: $P(X=0) = 0.8$ because the probability there are no typos is $1-0.2 = 0.8$.